# ssh How dose a second user log in with a ssh key file?

Tags: ssh, centos6, ssh-keys

I am new to VPS, I have linux centos 6 and have followed instructions [here](http://www.servermom.org/basic-centos-setup-before-building-a-working-server/414/) to get started.

I have create ssh key for the root user from instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lmE8NUt__w)

I have disabled root log in and created a second user.

My problem is how dose the second user log in with the private ssh key ?

I've searched the net for hours and cant find any clear instruction how the second user (which is me) is able to login in with a private key file.

I've jumped in to this head first im afraid so any advice would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The key is per user, so if you want to use the same private key to log in as your "second user" you will have to add the public key to the "second user"'s `authorized_keys`-file like you seem to have done for the root user.